# How to permut list level in R

Tags: r, list

is there's a way to permute list levels in R?
In other words, how can i simply go from test list to test2?

```
test=list(
a=list("alpha"=1:2,"beta"=3:5),
b=list("alpha"=5:6,"omega"=7:10)
)

test2 <- list(
alpha=list("a"=1:2,"b"=5:6),
beta=list("a"=3:5),
omega=list("b"=7:10)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
tst <- unlist(test, recursive = FALSE)
lst <- split(tst, gsub("[a-z]\\.|[0-9]", "", names(tst)))
lapply(lst, function(z) setNames(z, substring(names(z), 1, 1)))


# $alpha
# $alpha$a
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $alpha$b
# [1] 5 6
# 
# 
# $beta
# $beta$a
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# 
# $omega
# $omega$b
# [1]  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Indeed, it works! Thanks!
I also found this solution :
temp=unique(unlist(lapply(test,names)))
lapply(setNames(temp,temp),function(x) Filter(function( y ) !is.null(y),lapply(test, "[[", x)))